# CSS3 selectors p.para vs. p .para

Tags: html, css

I read the following, but I don;t fully understand the meaning of these selectors. Could you please provide an example showing the difference between them? Thx.

[image]

Comment: This is one of the most basic concepts in CSS. If you look up any guide or lesson on CSS selectors you'll find this explained.

Comment: That's CSS 1 not CSS 3. Also HTML 4, not 5.

Comment: @Quentin: I imagine he assumes 3 is part of the technology name, and not a version number. As most people new to web development do.

Comment: Why the downvotes!!! My answer is correct.

Comment: @BramVanroy, the topic on selectors is found in many references. However, not every reference list all possible example. I have checked several references and found no example for this case.

Comment: @Quentin, is there a new implementation for this case in CSS3?

Comment: @NoChance — No. The implementation of descendant combinators has remained unchanged (although their name has changed).

Comment: @NoChance — The official spec has an example for that case: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators

Comment: A class selector and a descendant selector are found in any basic CSS reference... As Quentin rightfully pointed out, you can also find an overview of all selectors in the spec.

Comment: @BramVanroy, thanks for pointing the duplicate, (although it is not exact duplicate),

Comment: @Quentin, thanks for pointing out the example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
p.para { /* <p class="para">, similar to p[class="para"] */
   color:red;
}

p .para { /* any descendants, that have class="para", of <p> */
   color:blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="para">
  P.Para {}
</p>

<p>
  <span class="para">
     P .Para {}
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: It's any descendant, not just children.

Comment: "any `<p>` with child that has class="para" */" — No. It selects the descendant, not the paragraph itself.

Comment: @Quentin you're right I lost terminology, thanks.

Comment: "any descendants of `<p>` that have class="para"" — That's ambiguous. It's "any descendants, that have class="para", of `<p>`"

Comment: @Quentin Corrected.

Answer (score -1):

```css
P{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}
P.para {
  color: red;
  }
P .para {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="para"> <!--P tag with class para-->
  sth
</p>
    
<p> <!--P with child having class para-->
  <span class="para"> 
    sth
  </span>
  xyz <!-- xyz is element of p -->
</p> <!--Or any descendant not just children-->
```

Both "sth" will change with any css rule but "xyz" is not.

Comment: It's any descendant, not just children.

Comment: "P with child having class para" — It selects the descendant, not the paragraph itself.

Comment: Thanks for warning.

Comment: Your example is a bit difficult to follow though. Thx.

Comment: @NoChance okay i try my best :)

Comment: Now it is more clear. Thx.

Comment: @NoChance I think now it is more clear.